# Can't Get "Hello World" to work with Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to follow along a PluralSight course on AngularJS Fundamentals. The guy's code and mine is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <!--[if IE]>
            <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1 ng-controller="HelloWorldCtrl">{{helloMessage}}</h1>
        </header>
        <section>
        </section>
        <footer>
        </footer>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function HelloWorldCtrl($scope) {
                $scope.helloMessage = "Hello World";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Yet it works for him and does not for me! What am I doing wrong? Seems like a pretty simple setup to me, yet it isn't working for me. I am not getting Hello World, instead I get:

> {{helloMessage}}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add [`ng-app`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angApp) attribute inside your `html` tag. Like this: `<html ng-app>`.

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/dBJmLr?p=preview