# Data binding in Angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

When i am using angular version this.
      "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js"
my code works fine. but when i am using this angular version my code is not working.
      "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js".

Full HTML code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="">
    <script src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <head>
    <title>Angular Js Tutorial</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <div ng-controller="Maincontroller">
             {{message}}
         </div>
        <script>
             function Maincontroller($scope)
              {
                  $scope.message = "Hii how are you";
              }
        </script>
    </body>
   </html>
```

I didn't the required output. It simply prints.

```
   {{message}}
```

Comment: Can you provide some of your controller code or console output when the page is rendering? Odds are there is some exception not allowing the binding to complete

Comment: Error from console of firefox."Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/ng/areq?p0=Maincontroller&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
I/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:6:416
qb@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:22:131
Sa@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:22:218
Xe/this.$get</<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:80:81

Answer (score 3):

Starting from angular 1.3 you can't declare controllers in the global scope.

Rewrite the declaration of your controller `MainController`

```
// Declaration of the module
angular.module('myApp', []);

// Declaration of the controller
angular.module('myApp').controller('MainController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Hii how are you";
});
```

Regarding to the above changes, replace `<html ng-app="">` with `<html ng-app="myApp">`

Comment: Great ! i have posted the same below

Answer (score 1):

There are few problems with your code,

(i)You have not declared module anywhere.
(ii) With Angular 1.3 you the controllers should not be declared globally.

Here is the corrected [`application`](http://plnkr.co/edit/2erYW3dUgMRGva1mIpPC?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <title>Angular Js Tutorial</title>
    <script src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body >
    <div ng-controller="MainController as mainCtrl">
      {{ mainCtrl.message }}
    </div>
    <script>
      (function() {
        'use strict';
        angular
          .module('app', []);
          .controller('MainController', ['$scope', function MainController($scope) {
              $scope.message = "Hii how are you";
        }]);
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31156084/my-hello-world-angular-program-is-not-working-in-1-3-14-version).

Comment: If you are using `MainController as mainCtrl`, don't use `$scope`. Use `this`.

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Angular JS Controller Example</title>
<script src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/
1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>AngularJS Sample Controller Application</h2>

<div ng-app = "ukApp" ng-controller = "ukController">
<br>         
{{name}}
</div>

<script>
var mainApp = angular.module("ukApp", []);
mainApp.controller('ukController', function($scope) { 
$scope.name= "Umar Farooque Khan";
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Use the above code to do above task.